# Why my CheckBox.Checked Property will reset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, postback, pageload

Using: .NET 3.5SP1, VS2008

I was editting someone else asp.net script, he did the Data retreving at the `Page_Load` while Page is not postback.

I could see the data was populated into the DropDownList properly even after I refresh, navigates, postback in the page.

I added couples more DropDownList and some CheckBoxes into the script, only the DropDownList I added got populated properly.  But not the CheckBox.

So I do a test in a new project, which is similar to its script structure:

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <% 
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Item2")
            {                
        %>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="CheckBox 1" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Code-Behind:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.CheckBox1.Checked = true;
                this.CheckBox1.Text = "Hello CheckBox";
                this.TextBox1.Text = "Hello TextBox";
                this.DropDownList2.SelectedValue = "Item2";
            }
        }
    }
```

So as you see the code, when the page first load, the `CheckBox1`'s text will change, `Checked` will be true, so as other `TextBox` and `DropDownList2`

After I select `DropDownList1`'s item to `Item2`, when the `CheckBox1`, `TextBox1`, `DropDownList2` nothing got setted, except the `CheckBox1.Text`.

Why is this happen?

EDIT:

I tried to put them into Panel, in this way it work.  But the problem is the program I am editting is using the format above.. So I am not allow to change them all to Panel.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <% 
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Item2")
            {
                this.MyPanel.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.MyPanel.Visible = false;
            }
        %>
        <asp:Panel ID="MyPanel" runat="server" Visible="false" >
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="CheckBox 1" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </asp:Panel>

    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why are you putting code in you aspx form?

Comment: @IrishChieftain is not me, is my previous developer.  I have no choice but to continue to modify his code

Comment: Re-create the problem in a new, test page. This markup is horrendous. Put your code in the code-behind file and try debugging it again.

Comment: Why? OP is showing right problem already.

Comment: Code does not belong in the markup, period.

Comment: @IrishChieftain this is already in a new, test page as I stated in the OP.

Comment: Ok. Did you try overloading the SaveViewState and LoadViewState methods to persist state of the controls in question? I frequently have to do this for check boxes and radio buttons selections - known issue.

Comment: @IrishChieftain I found a post of your solution in SO. I dont' know if you mean override the Page's SaveViewState and LoadViewState, then retrieve the ViewState at LoadViewState and store it back to the CheckBox. I have tried, but it doesn't work.  The CheckBox.Checked got resetted after Page_Load (which is after LoadViewState). After couples hours, I figures out workaround using what `sll` suggested in his comment, hidden field + CheckedOnChanged.

Comment: Glad sll's solution worked for you, be sure to give him the points :) CheckBoxes and RadioButtons do not save their state on postback and I often have to override those two page methods in the code-behind... just an FYI

Comment: @IrishChieftain Of course.  Thanks for your suggest and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out setting `EnableViewState` and `ViewStateMode`, perhaps some of the parent controls has disabled it so default Inherit value has been applied.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx):

> The default value of the ViewStateMode property for a Web server
>   control in a page is **Inherit**. As a result, if you do not set this
>   property at either the page or the control level, the value of the
>   EnableViewState property determines view-state behavior.

```xml
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="CheckBox 1" 
              EnableViewState="true"
              ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```

Comment: try out adding `ViewStateMode` as well

Comment: It doesn't work too.  I even copy and paste your code.  And I am testing on the new project. So the Page basically nothing except the code I posted above.   But if I put all those controls into a `Panel` and set it Visable to false, then Visable it when I select the drop down item and it works...

Comment: Looks like you've faced following issue, see workarounds here: [ASP.Net Checkbox value at postback is wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523606/asp-net-checkbox-value-at-postback-is-wrong)

Comment: So what was the issue, how you fixed it?

Comment: I think this issues happen when the CheckBox created within a If Statement like above.  The behavior is very strange.  I tried to override every event on the page, I notice that the value will be reset before reaching `OnPreLoad`.  The way I fixed is using your suggested workaround, store values in hidden fields.  Then populate the values only when the issues happen.   But why the issues happen.... I have no idea.  I tried to do the same thing in ASP.NET 4.0 and is the same...

Comment: Thanks for elaborating this, it would be helpful for others as well.