# Check / Uncheck ASP CheckBox with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox

how can i check / uncheck the following ASP checkbox with JQuery?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbImg1" CssClass="cbImg1" Checked="true" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="130px" ForeColor="#909090" Font-Size="12px" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code :-

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbImg1" CssClass="cbImg1" Checked="true" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="130px" ForeColor="#909090" Font-Size="12px" />
```

in jQuery you can try [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) :-

```
$("#cbImg1").prop('checked', true); //// To check
$("#cbImg1").prop('checked', false); //// To un check
```

Comment: i think the issue is that i have update button and after i press it the checkbox control gets the value Checked="true". is it true? if yes how can i avoid it?

Comment: i dont think update button changes the state of checkbox unless there are some code done on that..your asp checkbox already having Checked="true" in ur question by the way!

Comment: do you require to make it visible ="false" ? i guess it is creating problem @user281812

Comment: i changed it with no result

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523606/asp-net-checkbox-value-at-postback-is-wrong @user281812

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand the solution

Answer (score 0):

First change your

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbImg1" CssClass="cbImg1" Checked="true" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="130px" ForeColor="#909090" Font-Size="12px" />
```

to

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="cbImg1" CssClass="cbImg1" Checked="true" style="display:none" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="130px" ForeColor="#909090" Font-Size="12px" />
```

remove Visible="false" and make it to display none.

Then let's say you have button, add the following script to it.

```
OnClientClick="buttonClick(); return false;
```

And add the javascript like...

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
                function buttonClick() {      

        $("#<%=cbImg1.ClientID %>").prop('checked', true);
        alert('Called');
       }


      </script>
```

See if the alert appears or not...

Comment: it works only when the checkbox is visible. i want the checkbox to be hidden and "display:none" doesnt work...

Comment: make sure you removed visible=false