# uncheck checkbox with same classname in jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I used jquery to set the checked/unchecked the checkboxes with same class name. I searched web at [jquery set checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044340/jquery-set-checkbox-checked). I tried to using prop and attr too. However it doesn't work for me, but I can disable the checkbox. Would someone tell me what I missing.

There is the jquery I used:

```
 <script language="javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

There are the checkbox in page:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkOne" runat="server" Text="One"  CssClass="optionsBoxes"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkTwo" runat="server" Text="Two"  CssClass="optionsBoxes"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkThree" runat="server" Text="Three"  CssClass="optionsBoxes"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkFour" runat="server" Text="Four"  CssClass="optionsBoxes"/>
```

My jquery:

```
$('.optionsBoxes').attr('checked', false);    
$('.optionsBoxes').prop('checked', true);                  
$('.optionsBoxes').attr('disabled', true);  //worked
```

Comment: maybe it is not possible, look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523606/asp-net-checkbox-value-at-postback-is-wrong

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
$('.optionsBoxes')
```

result in an array of input[type="checkbox"] elements?

You can try this approach:

```
$('.optionsBoxes').each(function() { $(this).prop('checked', false) });
```

Comment: I tried your code but it still doesn't work. I added the jquery version in my question. It the version I used cause the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @eewardbrosens, I used the developer tool to check the checkbox element. It shows that <span disabled="disabled" class="optionBoxes"><input name="chkOne" id="chkOne" type="checkbox" checkd="checked"/> . The span cause the problem.

Comment: I used the nextUntil and closest for looking the input tag, but it still doesn't work. var chk = $(this).closest("input"); chk.prop('checked', false);

Comment: Can you show the exact html output in your question?